# Firebase Analytics/Big Query Avg Time On Screen

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

For an iOS app using Firebase Analytics I am able to use Big Query to report on average time on a screen. The screens in the app display dynamic content and I would like to report on the time on screen per content.

An example being a mail app that has a mail list and mail details screen. The data on the mail details screen is dependent on which mail item was selected from the list. We want to report on the average time on the mail detail screen based on which mail item is being displayed. Is this possible?

In Google Analytics we set a Custom Dimension on the screen view and were able to report on this.